# What should we do when a session expires while we still view a page?

Tags: php

I have a page which contains `$_SESSION` variables. Now after a certain amount of time, all the sessions will expire which is fair enough. But the problem is that suddenly we get undefined notices on our $_SESSION variables as they are now expired.

So in this situation what is the best thing to do when a session expires. DO we just include a the `E ^ NOTICE` code in order to not show notices (afterwe know the page is fully complete with no errors), or are we expected to destroy a session using `session_destroy()` on the page, or is there other ways of not showing these undefined errors to the users who are viewing these pages on the browser and may view the page when the session has expired.

Below is my example code I have on how I have $_SESSION code displayed:

```
 <?php

    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60); //12 hours until session expires
    ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
    ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
    require_once 'init.php'; 

    session_start();  //starts sessions

    include('member.php');  //this php script also contains sessions


    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

    }


    if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
                //Declare my counter for the first time

                $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
                $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = intval($_POST['sessionNum']);
                $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;

        }

    if (isset($_POST['submitDetails']) && $_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
        $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
    }


    $sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];


    if (isset($_POST['textQuestion'])) {

    $_SESSION['textQuestion'] = $_POST['textQuestion'];

    }

    if (isset($_POST['textMarks'])) {

    $_SESSION['textMarks'] = $_POST['textMarks'];

    }

    if (isset($_POST['totalWeight'])) {

    $_SESSION['totalWeight'] = $_POST['totalWeight'];

    }

    if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

        $action = 'individualmarks.php'; 

    }elseif($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

        $action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: what is this `$_POST[‘sessionNum']` value? How is it generated?

Comment: SessionNum comes from a previous page

Comment: in another php script, do you set a field of the form leading to this script with `$_SESSION['sessionNum']` ?

Comment: oh, you're setting that value after a user logged in, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the presence of a particular sentinel value. e.g. if whatever you're doing with the session is for a login-protected system, then check the value of 
`isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true)`.

If the sentinel value(s) are not present, then something's happened to the session, and you should redirect the user elsewhere to restore things to the way they should be (e.g. show the login page).

Since you can't know in advance what page a "slow" user will hit, you have to assume the session can vanish at any time, and do the sentinel checks on EVERY page.

Answer (score 3):

You cn check with `isset()` function like you do with your $_POST vars and notices will dissapear

Comment: It's a good idea to always check to see if variables like this are available before trying to use them.

Comment: It looks to me like he's looking for a client side solution.

Comment: client side with $_SESSION ? Don't think so

Comment: That's my point. He can't access $_SESSION on the client side. Is that what he's looking for or not? Maybe I misunderstood his question.

Comment: He just wants to remove notices if $_SESSION doesen't exist

Comment: In that case, let's just use isset(). :)

Comment: If you just want to remove the notices, use this: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` - and place this at the beginning of your main php script. It's a good standard for a development environment, since you still see warning and fatal errors

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in a live site you will want to have error_reporting(0), so you won't see the notices.

If you don't want to see notices anymore, you need to check array keys as well. And you check by using `if(isset($_SESSION['some_key']))`

Once you do this, you can safely use that variable.